# What is the complexity of T(n) = T(3n/4) + 2T(n/2) + n?

Tags: algorithm, time-complexity, divide-and-conquer

I have having trouble solving the problem. I figured out that at last, it will be n[7^log n base (3/4)], what will be the answer.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it is a mathematics question not a computer programming question.

Comment: @RaymondChen But, we have many time complexity questions on StackOverflow and they can be related.

Answer (score 2):

You can rewrite the equation like the following:

```
T(n) = T(n/(4/3)) + 2T(n/2) + n
```

Now as `4/3 < 2`, We can say `T(n) < 3 T(n/(4/3)) + n`. Then using master theorem, `T(n) = O(n^{log_{4/3}(3)}) = O(n^{3.82})`. On the other, we can find a lower bound as `T(n) > 3T(n/2) + n`, `T(n) = Omega(n^{log_2(3)})=Omega(n^{1.58})`.

To find exact solution, you can use [Akra-Bazzi Theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Akra%E2%80%93Bazzi_method) as well:

```
a1 = 1, b1 = 3/4
a2 = 2, b2 = 1/2
```

Find a `p` such that:

```
(3/4)^p + 2 (1/2)^p = 1
```

`p ~ 2.17`. So, `T(n) = \Theta(n^{2.17} * (1 + int(u/u^{3.17},1,n)) ) = Theta(n^{2.17})` (as `int(u/u^{3.17},1,n) = int(1/u^{2.17},1,n) = O(1)`).

In sum:

```
T(n) = Theta(n^{2.17})
```

Comment: how do you know that T(n) < 3 T(n/(4/3)) + n and T(n) > 3T(n/2) + n ?

Comment: @user184868 For  T(n) < 3 T(n/(4/3)) + n, as $T(n/2) < T(n/(4/3)$. I replaced $T(n/2)$ with $T(n/(4/3))$. For the other, you can follow the same strategy.